# How do I allow customers to show a portion of my site at their Domain?

Tags: apache, redirect, dns

I have a website that contains company profiles.  These profiles have many pages within my site like products, services, etc.  Some of my users would like to use their profile on my site as their webpage.

eg. going to www.mycustomerswebsite.com loads their profile on my site, but doesn't redirect to my url.

I'd like to allow them to do this simply by pointing their DNS at my server.  The behavior I'm looking for is similar to what one can do on hosted wordpress.  I'm running Apache as my web server on Linux CentOS.

**What are my options for setting this up?**

Comment: This seems like a straightforward VirtualHost configuration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just apache serving static files, you create a wildcard virtualhost as per:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html

If (as is more likely) we are talking about a script generating pages on the fly, that script should be written to inspect SERVER_NAME to determine what content to produce - pseudocode:

```
names = {
  'customer1.example.org': 1,
  'customer2.example.org': 2,
};

if ($ENV[SERVER_NAME] == 'www.example.com') {
  regularHome();
}
else {
  produceHome(names[$ENV[SERVER_NAME]]);
}
```

Either way, you must make an association between mycustomerswebsite.com and your name for the same customer - perhaps they must input their domain into their settings on your site or perhaps you already have their domain set up.

After all that (and probably most difficult) is to get them to make a DNS change - they are the only ones who can do it - so that www is CNAMEd to your host.  You might want to create a special host record "customers.example.com" or some-such strictly for this purpose.  Create some documentation for your customers similar to wordpress's:

http://en.support.wordpress.com/domain-mapping/map-existing-domain/#instructions-for-mapping-an-existing-domain